# Not able to push docker images to docker private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have created docker private register in my local `"10.234.1.254"`
If i tag an image as `10.234.1.254:5000/hello-world` and try to push it from another vm to the vm where registry is running - **IT FAILS** with below error

```
The push refers to a repository [10.234.1.254:5000/hello-world]
unable to ping registry endpoint https://10.234.1.254:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.234.1.254:5000/v2/: EOF
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.234.1.254:5000/v1/_ping: EOF
```

I even tried putting `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 10.234.1.254:5000"` in `/etc/default/docker` and restart docker service. But still i get the same error.

How do i tag an image using IP address and port of the private docker registry and push it?

Comment: did you run `docker login 10.234.1.254:5000` first?

Comment: @BMW When i run login command from docker client, i get: Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://10.234.1.254:5000/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://10.234.1.254:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.234.1.254:5000/v2/: EOF

Comment: are the docker versions different or same on docker client and docker registry server?

Comment: locally, you should be able to use localhost: `docker push http://localhost:5000/hello-world`. But from another VM, you need https.

Comment: @BMW im using version 1.10.3 on both the VM

Comment: Does `curl -k https://10.234.1.254:5000/v2` returns something ? (You can add `-v` to get more informations

Answer (score 0):

met the same issue at macOSX, the docker version is:

```
➜  registry docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce-rc4
 API version:  1.34
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   587f1f0
 Built:        Thu Nov 16 01:17:06 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce-rc4
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.5
 Git commit:   587f1f0
 Built:        Thu Nov 16 01:43:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

➜  registry docker push 10.168.32.26:5000/metric-collector:dev
The push refers to repository [10.168.32.26:5000/metric-collector]
Get http://10.168.32.26:5000/v2/: EOF
➜  registry curl http://10.168.32.26:5000/v2/
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
➜  registry docker login 10.168.32.26:5000
Username: 1
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get http://10.168.32.26:5000/v2/: EOF
```